# typescript: interface for fixed size array

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in typescript define fixed size array. say, for example, in a function definition, I need to able to say

```
coord: (c:any) => number[]; //how to say it is an array of size 4
```

can I define an interface like we define a hash map

```
//this doesn't work
interface IArray{
  [number]
}
```

and also restrict max length to be 4.

Comment: I wish you could do `let a: number[2] = [ 0, 1 ]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's sort of awkward, but you can do it like this:

```
interface SizeFour<T> {
    0: T;
    1: T;
    2: T;
    3: T;
}

function fn(): SizeFour<string> {
    // Need to cast
    return <any>['', '', '', ''];   
}

var x = fn();
var a = x[0]; // a: string
var b = x[4]; // b: any; error if --noImplicitAny
```

Comment: thanks Ryan, but nothing prevent doing `var c = x[10]`. so no safety on the bounds. How this is possible as `10` (index/method) is not defined in the interface.

Answer (score 22):

You could return a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) instead of an array:

```
type array_of_4 = [number, number, number, number];

var myFixedLengthArray :array_of_4 = [1,2,3,4];

// the tuple can be used as an array:
console.log(myFixedLengthArray.join(','));
```

Comment: This does not restrict the array to a size of four, going beyond the fourth element will still work...

Answer (score 4):

Preventing someone from using an index into an array outside the bounds is not something that even C# can do. e.g. what is preventing you from doing :

```
var index = 123; 
sizeFour[index];
```

Or even requesting the index from the server?

So short answer "there isn't a declarative way of preventing this if you insist on using `[]`"

You could always do

```
var bar = {
   one : 'something',
   two: 'somethingelse'
   // etc. 
}
```

and then only use `.` i.e. `bar.one`

Answer (score 0):

There is a (hacky) way of doing that. It's basically adding a new optional element, which is the impossible type `never`, to the inner array interface. However, that doesn't work if the third element is `undefined`.

The code below is with the latest Typescript `v4.3.2`:

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#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)

```js
interface ArraySizeOfTwo {
  0: number;
  1: number;
  2?: never;
}

interface ArrayList {
  [index: number]: ArraySizeOfTwo;
}

const myArray: ArrayList = [
  [1, 2],
  [15, 20],
];

// Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
const myArray2: ArrayList = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [15, 20],
];

// Error: Property '1' is missing in type '[number]' but required in type 'ArraySizeOfTwo'.
const myArray3: ArrayList = [
  [1, 2],
  [15],
];

// Error: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
const myArray4: ArrayList = [
  [1, 2],
  [15, undefined],
];

// no errors :(
const myArray5: ArrayList = [
  [1, 2],
  [15, 20, undefined],
];
```